# NodeJS Throwing error without exiting

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am working on an application where several types of errors can be thrown.  For each different type of error, the node process must terminate with a different exit code.

At the moment I am throwing errors like:

`throw new Error1('Failed, because of reason 1');
throw new Error2('Failed, because of reason 2');`

However this causes the process to exit when the error is thrown with exit code 8 every time.

What I need is an elegant way  to throw specific exit codes depending on which error is thrown.  I.e. when I throw Error1, it should exit with code 1 and when I throw Error2 it should exit with code 2.

At the moment it just exits with code '8' every time.

I have looked at other articles and there are suggestions that using `process.on('uncaughtException', ...);` will work; and it does, however it requires 'catching' the error, re printing it out and then exiting.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: I did not realise those were Error1 and Error2 first time reading it. I have updated my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will let you do what you want:

```
Error8.prototype = Error.prototype
process.on('uncaughtException', handleErrors)
throw Error8("Bad news...")

function Error8(message) {
    this.name = "Error8"
    this.message = message || ''
    this.errorCode = 8
}
function handleErrors (e) {
    if (!e.errorCode) {
        console.log('Unknown exception occurred')
        process.exit(1)
    }

    console.log("ECODE-" + e.errorCode + ": " + e.message)
    process.exit(e.errorCode)
}
```